# What are some low maintenance plants I can use for my front yard?

Tags: plant-recommendations

I've got two sections in my front yard, each with one terrible looking plant. I've removed all other plants(mostly weeds). I want to remove the remaining two plants leaving me with a clean slate.

One section is an L-shape 8x4 section and the other is somewhat round 6ft in diameter around my light post. Both sections are currently filled with mulch to prevent weeds from growing.

What are some good options for bushes and "filler" plants that don't require much maintenance?Watering and some occasional trimming at most.

Comment: Where do you live? What is the climate like? Does this portion of your yard receive full sunlight or is it shaded?

Comment: Well, you could always put out plastic, fake plants. No maintenance at all. It does not always work though. Years ago when we had little spare time because of work, my wife wanted to put something in a planter out back, one that we knew we would never remember to water. So she "planted" fake ivy in it. That winter was a hard one, and when the deer came into our yard, they ate the fake ivy. (A true story.) :)

Answer (score 3):

depending on the space you plan to fill... Butterfly bush, yuccas, prickly pears, Daturas are popular in the desert southwest, farther north things like, service berry, bear berry, elderberries maybe some cotoneasters... maybe a smoke bush... then as far as kind of classic "bushes": Yews, the ever popular boxwood and euonymous and the classic privet could fill space.

I suggest going to a locally owned nursery and looking around, as they will know what does well where you are, and there may be some municipal/local incentive to purchase water wise plants...

Answer (score 1):

In general, plants that are native to your area will be very low maintenance, as they are adapted to where you live. Without knowing where you live, though, it would be very hard for us to make specific suggestions. Can you provide more info?

Comment: Kareem is in Ottowa, according to his profile page. Even so, bstpierre's question needs answering - which way the garden faces (east, north) and sun exposure (or not) is important.